# MacOs: "rtf can't be opened" when converting rtf to txt using terminal

Tags: macos, unix, file-conversion, rtf

I hope to convert some rtf files into txt files. However, when I tried

```
textutil -convert txt PathName/*.rtf
```

I got

```
Error reading PathName/FileName.rtf.  The file “FileName.rtf” couldn’t be opened.
```

I can open these files with MS Word but not with TextEdit or Preview. I am not sure where the problem occurs. Could someone please help me?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you make a copy of "Filename.rtf", change its name to "Filename.txt", and see if TextEdit and/or Preview can open it?

Comment: Yes, it works! But as I have over 10,000 RTF files, I wonder if some commands can do this automatically

Comment: I suggest *copying* the .rtf files to a new directory, renaming them to change the extension ([How do I change the extension of multiple files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19654)), and then running `textutil` on them. There may be other methods available, but as I suspect you're aware, it's best to try these things on a copy of the data.